# Trying to merge all multiple CSV files to one excel workbook

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am able to execute the below code in python 2.7 and able to merge all csv files to a single excel workbook . But when i am trying to execute in python 3.4 . Getting an error . Let me know if anyone faced this issue and sorted out . 
Code:-

```
import glob, csv, xlwt, os
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for filename in glob.glob(r'E:\BMCSoftware\Datastore\utility\BPM_Datastore_Utility\*.csv'):
    #print (filename)
    (f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    #print (f_name)
    (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    #print (f_short_name)
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
    #print (ws)
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        spamReader = csv.reader(f)
        for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
            for colx, value in enumerate(row):
                ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
    wb.save("f:\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
```

ERROR:-

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\Copy of DataStore.py", line 16, in <module>
    wb.save("f:\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
  File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.0.0-py3.4.egg\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 696, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.0.0-py3.4.egg\xlwt\CompoundDoc.py", line 262, in save
    f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f:\x0cind_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should either make double-backsashes or singe forward-slashes in

```
wb.save("f:\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
```

i.e. one of those:

```
wb.save("f:\\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
wb.save("f:/find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
```

hope that helps!

Comment: I tried as you suggested , still getting the error:'File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\Copy of DataStore.py", line 16, in <module>
    wb.save("f:\\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls")
  File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.0.0-py3.4.egg\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 696, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "E:\BMCSoftware\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.0.0-py3.4.egg\xlwt\CompoundDoc.py", line 262, in save
    f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f:\\find_acs_errors_ALL_EMEA.xls''

Comment: does the file exist? you write `w+b` (with the `+`) meaning "open for read+write". if you want to create a new file, write `wb` as mode. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open